# Post JSON do WordPress with authorization

Tags: json, wordpress, payment-gateway, payu

I'm trying to connect PayU gateway to my website.

When the payment is done it sends JSON to my notify url, i.e. localhost:3000/notify

However I'll need to save these data like payment_date, status etc. to the WordPress user who just paid.

Unfortunately wp_get_current_user() returns 0, so I guess user isn't authorized (logged in).

How can I do it to be able to get this JSON and save some payment data to the current user?

How should it be resolved properly?

Comment: I am Not a WordPress expect but I think the task here is that you need to create a separate table which would store the payment details. Get the user ID (not sure how that would be done. Maybe look at other plugins or WP plugin development guide.) and save the details with the payment id and user id and I think that should work.

Comment: I thought about it however I guess there is a better option.

Comment: What's the better option?

Comment: ok, just realized that get_user_meta works without login... Just need to send user id in transaction.